# When I try to call a function from a class in an async function there are endless requests being sent

Tags: node.js, promise, aws-sdk

I have a function inside of a class that is supposed to create a new auto scaling group in AWS. When I try to call the function, my bash terminal keeps sending endless number of requests.

```
createASG = async function(csm)
{

            const response = {
                    poolAsgName: csm._info.body["poolAsgName"],
                    region: csm._info.body["region"],
                    initialSize: csm._info.body["initialSize"],
                    MaxSize: csm._info.body["maxSize"]
            }

        const newauto = new AutoScalingGroupHandler(response.poolAsgName,response.region);
        try{

        return await newauto._createNewASG(response.initialSize,response.MaxSize);
        }
        catch(err){
            logger.error(err);
            return;
        }


};
```

_createNewASG:

```
_createNewASG(initialSize,MaxSize)
  {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


              const params = {
                    AutoScalingGroupName: this._poolAsgName,
                    LaunchConfigurationName: 'test',
                    MaxSize: MaxSize,
                    MinSize: initialSize,
                    AvailabilityZones: [this._region]
              };

              this._awsAutoScaling.createAutoScalingGroup(params, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {

                          reject(err);
                    } else{ 

                          resolve(data);
                    }



              });
        });
  }
```

I expected that the function would return a successful response, but instead my bash terminal continues spamming "Max request reach retry again in ..." in an endless loop of some sorts.

Comment: can you share the code for _createNewASG method ?

Comment: @TuhinDas I did now.